# NPM: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I was using gulp on the project, then i decide to deleted all the dev dependencies to switch to webpack, but every time i try to install using npm is get this error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-e80c4ef4\node_modules\are-we-there-yet' -> 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\.staging\are-we-there-yet-5db4c798'

npm ERR! path C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\acorn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\acorn' -> 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\.acorn.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MiguelFrias\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-04T11_54_23_587Z-debug.log
```

any idea what can be happening.

Comment: Got something very similar to this when trying to install Express in a folder that was in Dropbox. So instead I installed it to a temp folder outside Dropbox, and copied it in, and this solved my problem. Pretty annoying tho.

Comment: @kebman : after trying a number of suggestions you saved my day: dropbox,,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem, apparently is some kinda problem with the last version of npm, i was using `npm version 5.6.0` and i downgraded to `npm version 5.3.0`. This did work after all, after intall a couple packages i still get the same error.

ok change version of npm for the last `version 5.8.0` now everything working just perfect, before was some kind of problem with atom that denied the permission the building process to install the dependencies of the package.

Answer (score 95):

just **delete** package-lock.json file and then install packages, that's all you need and should be works

```
rm package-lock.json && npm i
```

Comment: you should stop yarn or npm scripts when you want to install packages, then you can run it again

Comment: Can you explain why this happens and why it is necessary to delete the lock.json?

Comment: where is this file package-lock.json?

Comment: @TriCore it's located at the root folder, same path with package.json

Comment: This did not work for me as the error occurred while installing a global package. Running `npm cache verify` did the trick.

Comment: That `package-lock.json` file is there for a reason. Deleting it and reinstalling without is a random change that could break things, introduce security vulnerabilities etc.

Answer (score 35):

When I got this error I looked for all running instances of node in my task manager (i use process explorer on windows) and close/kill all running instances of node. For me its often webstorm or vs code. After closing these programs and ensuring there is no running node process npm install works again.

Comment: yes one of the node app was running from another terminal. This was the case for me

Comment: It solution for me. NPM don't work into WSL, if we have many instance node process in the Windows Task Manager.

Comment: These the node instances were called by the VSCode in my case.

Comment: Yep, closing VSCode helped

Answer (score 24):

cache verify command resolved the issue for me

```
npm cache verify
```

Comment: This worked for me after 2 days of struggling with this error. Thanks

Comment: Running the above command worked for me. However, a prompt came to run sudo chown -R 501:20 "<path/to/your/.npm>" . After this I ran npm install and it worked fine. My node version v19.9.0 and npm 9.6.3.

Comment: I was trying to install Bootstrap and that command helped (then I realized another error told me to mkdir manually so probably this is what helped more)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest fix for me was:

```
npm uninstall -g
```

Then:

```
npm install -g
```

Answer (score 5):

I remove `node_modules` and `package_lock.json`. Then, `npm install` and it works

Answer (score 4):

Iam using 
-**node** v15.5.0

-**npm** v6.14.10

Try this:

1. close *"expo start"*
2. remove *"package-lock.json"*
3. Try to install packages now

example: npm i @react-navigation/native

**This will fix the issue.**

Answer (score 3):

The second line may give a hint on what's happening:

> ```
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-e80c4ef4\node_modules\are-we-there-yet' -> 'C:\Users\MiguelFrias\Desktop\Therabytes\node_modules\.staging\are-we-there-yet-5db4c798'
> ```

It looks like npm doesn't have enough permission on the folder you're trying to use.

You can try:

- Delete the npm_modules again.
- Open whatever editor/terminal you're using to `npm install` with admin permission.

Comment: Im using commander (Cmder), i already try with deleting the node_modules and run terminal as a admin but still happening the same

Answer (score 3):

I just retried to run

```
npm install
```

and it succeeded

Answer (score 3):

For me, package-lock.json was not created and script was failing before itself.

This fixed my issue:

```
- deleted my node_modules.
- npm cache clean 
- opened cmd as administrator at the repository folder
- logged-in to the https://registry.npmjs.org/ using username and passoward as few of my components needed authentication to install.
- npm i
```

Answer (score 3):

If you ever get this error, the hotfix is to follow these steps:

delete node-modules folder
run command npm cache clean --force
run command npm install
install the package again with npm install your-package-name

Answer (score 2):

Actually the current package you are installing has some dependencies which is not being found my npm. So, before installing this package just perform the following command. (It will install all your listed dependencies mentioned in package.json file which are necesaary to run your application)

```
npm install
```

It works...!

Answer (score 2):

Another thing I've seen a lot on projects that have been around and gone through multiple contributors:

- Double check to see if anyone on your team has simultaneously done a `npm install` and `yarn`.

The tell-tale sign is you'll see a `package-lock.json` (generated by npm) and `yarn-lock.json` (generated by yarn) in the same repo. This can cause side-effects from collisions in the `node_modules` folder.

You can try dumping that folder locally, establishing a package manager of choice for your project and instructing the whole team on best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by removing the package-lock.json with the command rm package-lock.json then you go to the Node.JS website you 'install it' by going to LTS then after your node is updated run npm install in your terminal and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was running command in Ubuntu wsl and it wasn't working so i tried running in cmd prompt and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check any package.json is open anywhere, then close it first then retry.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me I just deleted both **package-lock.json** & **node_modules** folder. Now everything works great

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to **sudo the npm install command**. Don't know why... Don't want to know either.

```
sudo npm install --save-dev my_package
```

Answer (score 1):

These steps work for me:

```
    1. run "npm cache verify" or 
    2. remove node_modules and package-lock.json
and rerun command)
```

Answer (score 0):

For not to delete package-lock.json or node_modules every time, just add file ".npmrc" with content "package-lock=false", or add this string if file ".npmrc" already exists.

Comment: what does this do?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be the fault of the package you are trying to install. If that package is a local package and has a node_modules folder. Try:

```sh
cd /path/to/package
rm -rf package-lock.json npm-shrinkwrap
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Happen to me when I was coding react native app with expo,
when I was run the app and try to install form npm happen that error.
**So just stop run the app and reinstall the package**
for me it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Updating npm to latest version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the answers from above worked for me:

1. Restart the computer ( in my case WSL );
2. Run the commands from bellow from your chosen terminal, not from VSCode terminal
3. npm cache clean -f
4. rm -rf node_modules
5. rm package-lock.json
6. npm install

Good luck! :) ✌

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I wanted to deploy my react app to github pages after running `npm run deploy` I go the error

```
npm build error enoent: no such file or directory, stat '/users/user/desktop/projects/properties/client/build'
```

I figure out that I forgot to add `predeploy` script, after adding it things worked perfectly

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "refine start",
    "build": "refine build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "refine": "refine",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

have same problem, it works when i shutdown the Visual Studio Code thats open for that project

Answer (score -1):

Deleting package-lock.json or node_modules & After running:

```
npm install -g npm
```

it is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me,

```
rm -rf ./**/node_modules
```

while I need `lerna bootstrap`

Answer (score -1):

Just update the node to the latest version.
It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me (on command line in Ubuntu):
Update Node using

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

followed by

```
sudo n 16.13.2
```

Closed and reopened shell, `cd` back into the correct repo and then

```
sudo install npm -g
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont run cmd in root of a directory.
there might be one directory inside which u try to run.
cd Directory
npm i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In may case, it was `next-i18next.config.js`,
that had duplicated languages in the `locales` value,
and `fallbackLng` with existing languages refer to existing languages.