# Getting error if i install any packege in react native npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-native

NPM VERSION - 6.13.4

NODE VERSION - v12.16.1

I am trying to install `npm i react-native-router-flux --save`

and getting error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path G:\reactnative\Testing\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-transform
npm ERR! dest G:\reactnative\Testing\node_modules\.babel-plugin-react-transform.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'G:\reactnative\Testing\node_modules\babel- 
plugin-react-transform' -> 'G:\reactnative\Testing\node_modules\.babel-plugin-react-transform.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bhaman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-29T08_40_57_081Z-debug.log
```

How can i solve this error any idea suggest me

i am checking this ANSWER [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654094) but getting no solutions

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this issue relate? https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1847

Comment: @keikai this file not found \node_modules\.babm.DELETE'

Comment: Try this: [cant install any npm package error 4058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERROR SOLVED

using this command

```
react-native start --reset-cache --verbose
```

[DOCUMENT LINK](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)