# Next build issue with file names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, next.js, rename

I encountered next issue:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/user/my-web/.next/export/en/cities/berlin.html' -> '/home/user/my-web/.next/server/pages/en/cities/berlin.html'

What's the problem? Name collision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discussed here:
[NPM: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651221/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rename)

Possible reason, some node process is running. Check the running processes.

Easiest fix, delete package-lock.json and then reinstall packages. If this does not work, refer the given link for other possible resolutions and explanations.