# GCP cloudbuild.yaml triggers npm in "'/workspace/package.json'" but need "'/workspace/ui/package.json'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, google-cloud-platform, yaml

configure Cloud Build to build and test Node.js but am getting error.

code snippet of cloudbuild.yml file

```
steps:
    - id: 'APP INSTAL NPM'
      name: node:$_NODE_VERSION
      entrypoint: npm
      args: ['install', '--prefix ./ui']
    - id: 'APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM'
      name: node:$_NODE_VERSION
      entrypoint: npm
      args: ['run', 'build', '--prefix ./ui']
timeout: 6000s # 20 minute
```

git reop inside ui directory i have a application so adding **--prefix** still getting this error

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! code ENOENT

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! syscall open

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! path /workspace/package.json

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! errno -2

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'

> Step #1 - "APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM": npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Comment: You can check out the threads having similar errors that you are facing: [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415958/what-could-cause-an-error-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a-file-no-conte), [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651221/npm-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rename)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are encountering this problem, GCP cloud-build has a [dir](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#dir) field to set the working directory. This snippet should work:

```
steps:
- id: 'APP INSTAL NPM'
  name: node:$_NODE_VERSION
  dir: 'ui'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- id: 'APP BUILD PROCESS WITH NODE NPM'
  name: node:$_NODE_VERSION
  dir: 'ui'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
```